# Referencing divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this set of divs

```
    <div id="main">
        <div id="lvl1">
            <div id="lvl1-1">
                lvl 1-1
            </div>

            <div id="lvl1-2">
                lvl 1-2
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="lvl2">
            <div id="lvl2-1">
                lvl 2-1
            </div>

            <div id="lvl2-2">
                lvl 2-2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way on jquery that I can select all the sub divs under #lvl1, lvl2 and put it in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
var divs = $("#lvl1 div, #lvl2 div");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var divs = $("#lvl1 > div, #lvl2 > div")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var divs = $("#main > div > div");
```